# jQuery with Cordova?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

i want to create a android application using Cordova, jQuery and jQuery-mobile
I wrote this code for include all the file  :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myScript.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
```

jQuery-mobile work perfectly but jQuery don't work i try to put some code in index.js at the end (this is index.js) :

```js
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

but it don't work and it don't work too if i write some code in myScript.js

Why i can't use jQuery if jQuery-mobile is fine ? 
Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because DOM is not fully loaded when `deviceready` starts. You can use the following code to initialize the app:

```
    var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
    var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, false);

    function deviceReady() {
      deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
    }

    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
    });

    $.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(init);

    function init() {
      // Your initialization code here
    }
```